# Linear algebra exercise about linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Determine for each of the following sets of vectors $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}\in V$, $\{w_1, w_2, w_3\}\in W$, how many linear maps $F:V\longrightarrow W$ there exist such that $\forall i$, $F(v_i)=w_i$:

1. $\{t^2+1, t+1, t^2+t\}\in V=\mathbb R[t]_{2}$, $\{1, t-1, t^2-t\}\in W=\mathbb R[t]_{2}$;
2. $\{t^2+1, t+1, t^2+t\}\in V=\mathbb R[t]_{2}$, $\{1, t-1, t^2-t\}\in W=\mathbb R[t]_{3}$;
3. $\{t^2+1, t+1, t^2+t\}\in V=\mathbb R[t]_{3}$, $\{1, t-1, t^2-t\}\in W=\mathbb R[t]_{2}$.

I cannot start the exercise. Some helps?

Thank you

Comment: No, the exercise asks for $F(v_i)=w_i$ for every $i$.

Comment: How can I determine how many linear maps there exist?

Comment: Why there cannot be infinite?

Comment: can you imagine others?

Comment: Man, I want to know how many linear maps $F$ there exist such that $F(v_i)=w_i$ for every $i$. You said that there exists only one in the three cases. Why? What is your argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of vectors  $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a basis of $V$in the first two cases. Therefore a linear map  from $V$ to *any* vector space is uniquely determined by the  values of  the $F(v_i)$s.

In the third case, this set can be completed  by a fourth vector, say $v_4$, to obtain a basis of $V$, and the linear map is uniquely determined by the image of $v_4$ (and of course the prescribed images of $v_1, v_2,v_3$). Therefore the set of linear maps we seek for corresponds bijectively to $W$.

Comment: In the third case, the set of vectors you write is not a basis...

Comment: Oops ! It seems I overread the details

Comment: @Bernard in the third case, there exist infinitely many maps with that property. Indeed, you can define freely $F(v_4)$. For this reason the maps $F$ such that $F(v_i)=w_i$ for every $i$ are infinite.

Comment: @Redeldio: did I write the contrary?

Comment: Absolutely not, I just wanted to precise this fact. I accepted your answer!